# Bootstrap validator issue with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am having an issue with Bootstrap Validator. For some reason, even when every single field is correct, I am unable to have the submit button work. When you click the button when everything is filled out, an error icon appears over it. Any ideas why this might be? I have tried a few different things with no success. I am not sure if this is by something I did but I am pretty sure I am following the documentation exactly as it should be. Would appreciate if someone can take a look at this. Thanks!

```js
//If hash is detected from another page
$(document).ready(function() { 
   if ( window.location.hash == "#recipe" ) {   
  $('#recipeQuestions').trigger('click');
   }
});

<!-- Recipe Form Validation -->
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#recipeForm').bootstrapValidator({ 
        container: '#messagesRecipe',
        //feedbackIcons: {
            //valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            //invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            //validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        //},
  live: 'enabled',
        fields: { 
            firstName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your first name'
                    }
                }
            },
   lastName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your last name'
                    }
                }
            },
   street1: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your street address'
                    }
                }
            },
   city: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter a city'
                    }
                }
            },
   state: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter a state'
                    }
                }
            },
   zip: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter a zip code'
                    }
                }
            },
   phone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your phone number'
                    }
                }
            },
   email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter your email address'
                    }
                }
            },
   recipeName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter a recipe name'
                    }
                }
            },
   recipeOrigin: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter origin of recipe'
                    }
                }
            }
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Bootstrap Validator CSS -->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootsrap Validator Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

<!-- RECIPE FORM Start -->
            <div id="recipeForm" class="col-md-12">
                <span id="recipe"></span>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>RECIPE QUESTION</h1>
      
      <form class="recipeForm" method="POST">

       <div class="form-group"> <!-- First Name -->
        <label for="first_name_id" class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="John">
       </div> 
       
       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Last Name -->
        <label for="last_name_id" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe">
       </div> 

       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Street 1 -->
        <label for="street1_id" class="control-label">Street Address 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street1" placeholder="Street address, P.O. box, company name, c/o">
       </div>     

       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Street 2 -->
        <label for="street2_id" class="control-label">Street Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street2" placeholder="Apartment, suite, unit, building, floor, etc.">
       </div> 

       <div class="form-group"> <!-- City-->
        <label for="city_id" class="control-label">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Birmingham">
       </div>         

       <div class="form-group"> <!-- State Button -->
        <label for="state_id" class="control-label">State</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="state">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
         <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
         <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
         <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
         <option value="CA">California</option>
         <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
         <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
         <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
         <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
         <option value="FL">Florida</option>
         <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
         <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
         <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
         <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
         <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
         <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
         <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
         <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
         <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
         <option value="ME">Maine</option>
         <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
         <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
         <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
         <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
         <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
         <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
         <option value="MT">Montana</option>
         <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
         <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
         <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
         <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
         <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
         <option value="NY">New York</option>
         <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
         <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
         <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
         <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
         <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
         <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
         <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
         <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
         <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
         <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
         <option value="TX">Texas</option>
         <option value="UT">Utah</option>
         <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
         <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
         <option value="WA">Washington</option>
         <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
         <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
         <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>     
       </div> 

       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Zip Code-->
        <label for="zip_id" class="control-label">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" placeholder="#####">
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Phone -->
        <label for="phone_id" class="control-label">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="555-555-5555">
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Email -->
        <label for="email_id" class="control-label">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="jdoe@example.com">
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Recipe Name -->
        <label for="recipe_name_id" class="control-label">Recipe Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipeName" placeholder="Traditional Lasagne">
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Recipe Origin -->
        <label for="recipe_id" class="control-label">Recipe Origin</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="recipeOrigin">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="product_packaging">Product Packaging</option>
         <option value="cento_website">Cento Website</option>
         <option value="cookbook">Cookbook</option>
        </select>     
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Comments -->
        <label class="control-label" for="comments">Comments</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" name="comments" rows="10"></textarea>
       </div>
       
       <!-- Errors -->
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div id="messagesRecipe"></div>
         <br> 
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group"> <!-- Submit Button --> 
         <button type="submit" name="recipeConcern_Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info btn-large">Submit</button>
       </div>     

      </form> 
       
     </div> 
    </div> 
         </div>
   <!-- RECIPE FORM End -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem yet, but i noticed that $('#recipeForm') references the div parent and not the form, try switching the id attribute out and try again! worth a try .. lemme know!

Comment: @animake that looks like it was the problem! it submits the form, but the button still has the disabled attribute. its odd but its working i think

Comment: nice to hear that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#recipeForm')` references the div parent and not the form, try switching the id attribute to the form.